# Vim: Conditionally use fugitive#statusline function in vimrc

Tags: git, vim

I use the same vimrc across many machines, some of which have fugitive.vim installed and some of which don't. I like including `fugitive#statusline()` in my statusline, but on machines that don't have the plugin installed this raises an error.

Is there a way to check for this function's existence before calling `set statusline`? I've tried using `exists`y, but it doesn't work for some reason (load order?)

```
if exists("*fugitive#statusline")
  set statusline=%<\ %f\ %{fugitive#statusline()} ... (other stuff)
endif
```

I've also tried silencing the error by prefixing the command with `silent!` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 10):

This one would be a shortcut:

```
set statusline+=%{exists('g:loaded_fugitive')?fugitive#statusline():''}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it, but the variable `g:loaded_fugitive` is either empty or non-existent at the time `vimrc` is executed.

Comment: @Christopher: please check your `vim-fugitive` installation, because `g:loaded_fugitive` is defined in `fugitive.vim`, and this kind of interpolation is done whenever the statusline is evaluated, not just the time `vimrc` is executed.

Comment: @tungd There is no reason for `g:loaded_fugitive` be loaded *before* vimrc unless you manually trigger loading using some means.

Comment: @ZyX: In fact the plugin is always loaded after the `vimrc`, this is clearly documented in `:help initialization`. However this still work as expected since the `%{}` means evaluate the expression whenever the statusline is updated.

Comment: @tungd A, you are right. I am generally avoiding such solutions (I mean, performing the check 100500 times where 1 is sufficient) though, but it is valid and does not add that much overhead.

Answer (score 8):

As fugitive does not define `fugitive#statusline` in an `autoload` directory it sadly can not be sniffed use `silent! call` / `exists` technique (Thank you @Christopher). There are however some alternatives:

- Put a ternary branch in your `'statusline'` option as @tungd suggested.
- Set `'statusline'` in an `after/plugin` file like @Christopher suggests. This solves the problem but means your statusline is defined in an rather unlikely place so it would probably be best to put in a nice comment in your `~/.vimrc` file.
- Simply define the function in your `~/.vimrc` file.

Example:

```
if !exists('*fugitive#statusline')
  function! fugitive#statusline()
      return ''
  endfunction
endif
```

- Another option is to use a `Fugitive` `autocmd` event that Fugitive defines. Note that this will only fire when Fugitive detects a git directory.

Put something like this in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
augroup fugitive_status
  autocmd!
  autocmd user Fugitive set statusline=%<\ %f\ %{fugitive#statusline()} ...
augroup END
```

Personally I think @tungd solution is the simplest. However just define a dummy function would be my next choice. Fugitive will override it if Fugitive is installed. The best part is this keeps your `'statusline'` option neat and clean.

Comment: Dummy function should contain `return ''` I believe. Otherwise it returns number `0` which will be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have worked out how to achieve this. The check for existence of `fugitive#statusline()` needs to happen **after** the plugins are loaded. Until then, no fugitive related variables or functions are loaded.

Add this code file in the `$VIMRUNTIME/after/plugin` path:

```
" $VIMRUNTIME/after/plugin/fugitive-statusline.vim
if has("statusline") && exists('*fugitive#statusline')
    " git fugitive statusline
    set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%{fugitive#statusline()}%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P

    " show statusline always
    set laststatus=2

    " turn off ruler
    set noruler
endif
```

Comment: Do explain. Files in autoload/ are loaded automatically in exactly one case: when somebody tries to use undefined function or variable. When we force loading the functions and variables that may have triggered automatic loading become defined effectively purging out reasons for loading files automatically for the second time. It is not plugin directory which is going to get sourced after vimrc no matter whether file in it was or was not sourced already or other directory like this.

Comment: F*cking fugitive plugin defined this function in `plugin/fugitive.vim` and not in `autoload/fugitive.vim` where it is supposed to be located (based on the function name) which means that my solution does not *work* (it still does not trigger out-of-order run: it is not triggering any run at all) and neither does Peter Rincker’s one. If function was defined in `autoload/` then previous comment applies and @Peter Rincker answer turns to be good. There is still no way loading `autoload/fugitive.vim` should cause any trouble, but it simply does not exist.

Comment: ^^^ Duplicating my two comments to my answer (it was deleted) as I am not sure whether you can see comments to deleted answer. To follow conversation: “Should we really be subverting the order of processing, but running autoload/fugitive.vim out of order. This could have unintended consequences. – Christopher” is the comment the first my comment is replying to. My answer was to load `autoload/fugitive.vim` with `:runtime` and then check for function existence.

Comment: @ZyX Fugitive really threw me for a loop too. I have removed my post as it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking the loaded variable of the fugitive plugin?

```
if exists('g:loaded_fugitive')
   set statusline=%<\ %f\ %{fugitive#statusline()} ... (other stuff)
endif
```

although if the existance of the fugitive#statusline isn't working this might not be that effective!

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried it, but the variable `g:loaded_fugitive` is either empty or non-existent at the time `vimrc` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

In your vimrc or init.vim file

```
set statusline=%F%r%h%w%=(%{&ff}/%Y)\ (line\ %l\/%L,\ col\ %c)\

if exists("*fugitive#statusline")
  set statusline+=%{fugitive#statusline()}
endif
```